# How can I determine the equality of more of 2 numbers? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, equality

Hy, I need to determine the equality of 4 numbers. The numbers are size(A,1), size(B,1), size(C,1) and size(D,1), where, for example 
A=[1 2; 3 4], B=[1 2 3, 4 5 6], C=[1 2; 3 4; 5 6] and D=[1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]
I have tried with this but it doesn´t work because it compares from left to right.

```
size(A,1)==size(B,1)==size(C,1)==size(D,1)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the function `isequal`

which does Array Equality checks:

```
isequal(size(A,1),size(B,1),size(C,1),size(D,1))
```

Comment: @Traker you are welcome, also beware that isequal works for array compare as well as single values.

Comment: @Traker also note that in general this is not a good idea (i.e. comparing the equality of doubles), because of rounding errors. Here it's safe, though, because sizes are converted straight from integers.

Answer (score 0):

Put the sizes in a vector. The you could use

1. [`variance`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html). The variance should be zero if all elements are the same.

Example:

```
Q=[size(A,1) size(B,1) size(C,1) size(D,1)]; 
var(Q)==0 
ans = 0    % // Values are not equal
```

A few other examples

```
B=[6 6 6 6];
var(B)==0
ans =  1 % // All values are equal

T=[5 4 6];
var(T)==0
ans = 0 % // values are not equal
```

---

2. [`range`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/range.html). `range(X)` returns the difference between the maximum and the minimum of a sample. This should be zero if all elements are equal.

Example:

```
range(Q)==0
ans = 0 % // Values are not equal

range(B)==0
ans =  1 % // Values are equal

range(T)==0
ans = 0 % // Values are not equal
```

Comment: I think this is not correct. If you have `T=[5 4 6]` and you do this: `mean(T)==t(1)` the result is 1 and not every components are equal